# C# Button Too each Music

Tags: c#

I had some difficulty trying to make my program make buttons for each song, like say I have 6 songs in a folder, what program should do is get them all in and generate button to each song and when I press them they will play their own song. I can't really even think where to start at this point, I got FolderBrowsingDiaglog running I just need to figure this part out. I added the code that you gave me and it gives me an error of that i have illegal characters in path.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog folderChoice = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (folderChoice.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (string fname in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderChoice.SelectedPath + @"*.mp3"))
            {
                Button btn = new Button
                {
                    Text = fname.Split('\\').LastOrDefault(),
                    Location = new Point(10, 10 + i++ * 30),   //sample x,y
                    Size = new Size(100, 20),
                    Tag = fname,   //For having the file location
                };
                this.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us your code - what have you tried so far and what did not worked? Where do you stuck? Can you create just 1 button, for example? Also specifying what is your platform (WPF or WinForms) will help a lot

Comment: Indeed, this question is too general to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well creating buttons is easy:

```
if(folderBrDlg.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.Ok)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(string fname in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles())
    {

         Button btn = new Button
         { 
               Text = fname.Split('\\').LastOrDefault(),
               Location = new Point(10, 10 + i++ * 30),   //sample x,y
               Size = new Size(100,20),
               Tag = fname,   //For having the file location
               ....
         };
         btn.Click += (s, e) =>
         {
              string fileToPlay = (string)((Button)s).Tag; 
              //now you only have to play it.
         }
         this.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I added the click event for the button to that on click of every button you can get the path of the related file, and you just have to use a player to play it.

Comment: this really helps full, I just get an error of illegal characters in path.

Comment: add a try/catch around the GetFiles() and see if you can find out what the illegal characters are.  You may need to write a method to cleanup the illegal characters before you attempt to create your song buttons

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I just made directory wrong and that's it, and i didnt make try/catch, now i need to add code so it plays when its pressed and i make it os buttons dont over lap each other

Comment: @MarkKrikunov glad it helped. if you have saved the file path in the tag for you can add click event for each button in the above loop. I add the code

Comment: Great, thank for your help. You were really helpful.

Comment: @MarkKrikunov you are very welcome

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding of the question. 
1. You want to make a program that plays one of your six songs when one of the buttons are clicked

FolderbrowsingDialog will allow to choose the files you want to play but it won't let you play them. Consider using the SoundPlayer class. SoundPlayer will give you the functionality to play the songs but these songs need to be .wav files.The microsoft link will help you get a better about the SoundPlayer class.

From this you should be able to finish your program.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20909363)

Comment: Well he didn't really specify what he wants to do in detail so I answered him generically form my understanding but thank you for this. I'll use it in future reference